# AttributeError: on BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import datetime



date = str(datetime.datetime.today().date()).split("-")
date_year_month = f"{date[0]}/{date[1]}"
src_code = []

for index in range(int(date[2]) - 2, int(date[2]) + 3):
    URL = requests.get(
        f"https://www.yallakora.com/Match-Center/?date={date_year_month}/{index}")

    src = URL.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    championship = soup.find_all("div", {'class': 'matchCard'})
    print(BeautifulSoup(championship))

    print("Successful Connection")
```

these code should be run without any problems but it give error and i don't understand what these error

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `BeautifulSoup(championship)`? `championship` is already a BS object. The argument to `BeautifulSoup()` should be text to parse. I think what you want is `print(championship.prettify())`

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling BeautifulSoup before, instead of

```
print(BeautifulSoup(championship))
```

you just need to do

```
print(championship)
```

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't work